# wiring electric motor to run CW without name plate or diagram information, other than my diagram of it running CCW

Tags: induction-motor, single-phase

[image]

Motor does not have name plate or diagram. It is running CCW rotation now.
From my wiring diagram is it possible to re-wire to run CW? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since AC alternates voltage, you cannot do this at all by alternating two wires to the motor but rather from the motor two windings inside.  https://woodgears.ca/motors/reversing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. With just the information given it is not possible to determine how to re-wire the motor to run CW. It is also not possible to determine if there is sufficient access to internal connections to do that. Since this motor has a capacitor, it is almost certainly a single-phase induction motor. To reverse such a motor, it is necessary to reverse the connection of the auxiliary (start) winding with respect to the main (run) winding. In many motors, the two windings are connected together internally and it may not be possible to break the internal connection and reliably reconnect it to a different point even if the motor is partly or totally disassemble.

An experienced person might be able to determine how the motor is wired internally by testing the motor in various ways while operating and while disconnected from power. It might help to know how the motor was originally used and connected externally. The original equipment may even have a diagram.

Comment: Yes. In most single phase motors that follow NEMA terminal designations, as this one appears to do, you need to swap T5 and T8. Your motor does not appear to have a T5 or a T8 lead brought out, rendering it non-reversible. You could take it to a motor rewind shop to have them disassemble the motor and cut into the leads to create those connections, for which the labor charges will likely exceed the cost of buying a reversible motor.